# How to create First Date Flag Column Per Customer/Client in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this in SQL Server:

| Client_Name | Client_ID | Purchase_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Dee | 2563 | 11/15/2022 |
| John Dee | 2563 | 11/29/2022 |
| Sara Spence | 7985 | 4/17/2022 |
| Sara Spence | 7985 | 5/12/2022 |
| Sara Spence | 7985 | 7/15/2022 |
| Mark Brown | 8635 | 1/23/2021 |
| Mark Brown | 8635 | 1/30/2021 |
| Mark Brown | 8635 | 6/20/2021 |

I want a query to create a flag column to identify first purchase date per client, expecting the result like this:

| Client_Name | Client_ID | Purchase_Date | First_Purchase_Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Dee | 2563 | 11/15/2022 | 1 |
| John Dee | 2563 | 11/29/2022 | 0 |
| Sara Spence | 7985 | 4/17/2022 | 1 |
| Sara Spence | 7985 | 5/12/2022 | 0 |
| Sara Spence | 7985 | 7/15/2022 | 0 |
| Mark Brown | 8635 | 1/23/2021 | 1 |
| Mark Brown | 8635 | 1/30/2021 | 0 |
| Mark Brown | 8635 | 6/20/2021 | 0 |

Is there any solution create that flag column using a case statement? I have thousands of rows and tens of columns in the table.

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
CASE 
WHEN Purchase_Date = MIN(Purchase_Date) OVER (ORDER BY Client_ID) THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END AS First_Purchase_Flag
```

Version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64) Jan 12 2022 22:30:08 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: All you need to do is change `ORDER BY` to `PARTITION BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilise a *window function* but like this:

```
CASE WHEN Purchase_Date = MIN(Purchase_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Client_Id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

An alternative would be

```
CASE WHEN Purchase_Date = FIRST_VALUE(Purchase_Date) OVER (PARTITION by Client_Id order by Purchase_Date ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

In either case your are dealing with each `Client_Id` as a group so you *partition* by this.

Answer (score 1):

Hi for this case you will want to create a windowing function using row_number(). a windowing function will apply the function over a window, which you can think of as a group. In the below code the row_number() function is being applied over a group created by client_names

```
select
Client_Name,
Client_ID,
Purchase_Date,
row_number() over (partition by client_name order by Purchase_Date desc) as First_Purchase_Flag
```

then you can create a case statement to flag all rows with a number 1

```
select
Client_Name,
Client_ID,
Purchase_Date,
First_Purchase_Flag,
case when First_Purchase_Flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end as First_Purchase_Ind
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable
(
    Client_Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Client_ID INT,
    Purchase_Date DATE
)

INSERT INTO #TestTable (Client_Name,Client_ID,Purchase_Date)
SELECT * FROM
(
VALUES
    ('John Dee',2563,'11/15/2022'),
    ('John Dee',2563,'11/29/2022'),
    ('Sara Spence',7985,'4/17/2022'),
    ('Sara Spence',7985,'5/12/2022'),
    ('Sara Spence',7985,'7/15/2022'),
    ('Mark Brown',8635,'1/23/2021'),
    ('Mark Brown',8635,'1/30/2021'),
    ('Mark Brown',8635,'6/20/2021')
) As RawData (Client_Name,Client_ID,Purchase_Date)


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        Client_Name,
        Client_ID,
        Purchase_Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client_ID ORDER BY Purchase_Date ASC) AS PurchaseOrdinal
    FROM #TestTable
)

    SELECT 
        Client_Name,
        Client_ID,
        Purchase_Date,
        IIF(PurchaseOrdinal = 1, 1, 0) AS First_Purchase_Flag
    FROM CTE
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?